# Why calling a function inside a Python class __init__ can be both Attribute and Method?

Tags: python, python-class

I am quite confused with the **method** and **attribute** of a Python class. Suppose we have a Python class like this:

```
# case 1
class Person:

    def __init__(self, first, last):

        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.fun()

    def fun(self):
        value = self.first + '---' + self.last
        self.fun = value
        return value

person_1 = Person('A', 'B')  
person_1.fun

---> "A---B"
```

As we can see, in **case_1** we initialize an instance `person_1`. And we can get the result we want by calling `fun` as an **attribute**. However, if we change our code to the following, `fun` becomes a **method** instead.**(case_2)**

```
# case 2
class Person:

    def __init__(self, first, last):

        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.fun()

    def fun(self):
        value = self.first + '---' + self.last
        return value

person_1 = Person('A', 'B')  
person_1.fun

---> <bound method Person.fun of <__main__.Person object at 0x7fd4f79168d0>>
```

We still contain the init process in the class. But now `fun` becomes a **method** but not an **attribute**. **(case_2)**

If we remove the `self.fun()` in `init` but keep the `self.fun = value`, it is still a **method**. **(case_3)**

```
# case 3
class Person:

    def __init__(self, first, last):

        self.first = first
        self.last = last

    def fun(self):
        value = self.first + '---' + self.last
        self.fun = value
        return value

person_1 = Person('A', 'B')  
person_1.fun

---> <bound method Person.fun of <__main__.Person object at 0x7fd4f797f390>>
```

Would you mind giving me some instructions about why this happens? And what is the proper way to use the function as an attribute inside a Python Class? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: It is really hard to understand what you are confusing to me. Methods *are attributes*, attributes of the class that happen to be functions. In case 1), you call `self.fun()` in `__init__`, this runs the `fun` method. Inside that `fun` method, you assign `self.fun = value`, which *shadows* the method with an instance attribute. In the second case 2), you *don't* assign to `self.fun`, and in the third case, you don't call the `fun` method, but if you did, it would end up shadowing the method with that instance attribute

Comment: In *any* case, you probably should *never* shadow a method like that with an instance attribute, it's confusing. I'm not sure what you mean by "And what is the proper way to use the function as an attribute inside a Python Class?".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, juanpa. I have this question because I was learning the decorator of Python. I was thinking if `@property` can define a class attribute as a function, why don't we just call this function inside the `init`? But as you said, it might be very confusing, and I should not do that.

Comment: That isn't what `property` objects do. They are *descriptors*. Indeed, function objects are descriptors too. Read the following: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the materials. They are really helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case 1, your constructor calls fun() which has a line inside of it to overwrite itself with an attribute value. This is confusing and not a good thing to do because it is confusing.

In case 2, your fun method does not include the line to overwrite itself so it doesn't get overwritten.

In case 3, you never actually call your fun method so it never has a chance to overwrite itself. If you called it with person_1.fun() i.e. with parentheses, then it would execute and overwrite itself and from that point on, person_1.fun would be an attribute value.

Remember that in python, a function/method ONLY executes if it is called with parentheses. If you don't express it with parentheses, then the result of evaluation is not the output of the function, but instead the expression produces a reference to the function itself, which can be put in another variable or in a data structure and called later.

To illustrate this:

```py
>>> def my_func():                                      
...     print('got called')                             
...     return 42                                       
...                                                     
>>> x = my_func #no parentheses, x becomes an alias to my_func                         
>>> y = my_func()  #parentheses means actually execute                                      
got called                                              
>>> y                                                   
42                                                      
>>> x                                                   
<function my_func at 0x765e8afdc0>                      
>>> x()  #x is a reference to my_func and can be called itself                                               
got called                                              
42                                                      
>>>
```

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I think I figure it out!

In case 1, we simply run the function `fun()` when we init the instance. And because it defines the attribute `self.fun = value` inside the `fun()`, hence `fun` can be used as an attribute. (It cannot be used as the method anymore, because it has been replaced as an attribute.)

In case 2, we only call and run this function. But `fun` is not been defined as an attribute inside the class. That's why it remains as a method.

In case 3, `fun` is a method, but in this method, we define an attribute `fun`. Hence we can first init an instance, then run the function `fun`. After that, the attribute `fun` is added to this instance, and then we can call it as `person_1.fun`.